# Symfony2 on ubuntu virtual host debug toolbar not found

Tags: symfony, apache2, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and created virtual host for Symfony project. I didn't change anything in the Symfony project yet but already as I try to load AcmeDemoBundle I get error `An error occured while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not found). Do you want to open profiler?`

I did some research but all I found is to do something with .htaccess file which didn't work. I have some suspicions that it might be my virtual host conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` the content of that file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName registration.dev
    ServerAlias www.registration.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/registration/web/
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Here a working file for your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test_symfony/web/
        DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    <Directory "/var/www/html/test_symfony/web/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```

The following url: `http://test.dev/home` will direct you to the home page without the debug toolbar. To make sure you got the tool bar specify the app_dev.php : `http://test.dev/app_dev.php/home`
hope it helps